# Warning: CSS Hot Reload ignoring

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

This is my first project after the release of .NET 8. When I removed originally came bootstrap v5.1 and added latest Bootstrap v5.3 via CDN this warning appears in my browser console. I have no idea what that it is.

Can anybody help me fix this problem?

> CSS Hot Reload ignoring https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css because it was inaccessible or had more than 5000 rules. browserLink:50:1248

[image]

My `_Layout` page is like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it has more than 5000 rules so hot reload can't hot reload it.   Annoying that it's in the console. but has no effect as you won't be changing it, so don't need the hot reload feature.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Community-2022-Version-17/10526532?pageSize=15&sort=active&topics=macos+10.13